# Multiple Filters for Single Object in SVG

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I want to put two filters on my circle. (Maybe more)

I've tried doing:

```
filter="url(#f1);url(#f2)"
```

And:

```
filter="url(#f1,#f2)"
```

And:

```
filter="url(#f1 #f2)"
```

But none of them work. How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could add multiple effects in one filter, however if you want to stack the filters up, first group the object and then apply the other filter to your object.

```
<g filter="url(#f2)">
<rect width="90" height="90" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" fill="yellow" filter="url(#f1)"/>
</g>
```

Comment: Nope. That's even worse than before. That just gets rid of all my filters inside the group.

Comment: @BadgerGirl: Interestingly, the example doesn't work in Opera. My intuition would have said the total opposite (like "if it works anywhere, then in Opera").

Comment: That's weird, maybe somebody else can come up with a better solution.

Comment: Oh really? This is strange because this example works for me in Opera.

Comment: @BadgerGirl: Ok, thanks for the "fiddle" :)  Yes, you're right, it does work, but only one way round.  You see I want the "f1" to be the one in the group, and "f2" to be in <rect>, but it doesn't work that way round :/

Comment: Okay, you answered my question. Thanks for your help :)   However, it would help me if you were able to tell me why it only works a certain way round.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 18):

I know this is a very old question, but for people referencing this, you can also just separate your filter functions with spaces - `filter="url(#f1) url(#f2)"` should work

See: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, it's currently a viable solution (tested in Firefox and Chrome), provided that `f2`'s input is `SourceGraphic`

Comment: This method made my SVG darker somehow. But if I combine the filters using `<g>` like Badger Cat suggests, this is not a problem

Comment: @HolgerL Yes, when I try this method, I run into the strange darking problem too.  I posted a question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73067146/css-filter-composed-of-multiple-svg-filters-makes-image-darker

Comment: This does work in the browser, but not in Inkscape (v1.2.1). As alternative, create a dedicated group for each filter (bad for the SVG hierarchy but works).

Answer (score 7):

Start with an identity feColorMatrix and name the result currentGraphic for example. Use that as 'in' for each filter element bundle/transaction start and as 'result' for the final operation of the bundle. The next element bundle picks it up at 'in'='currentGraphic', etc.

Comment: Can you make an example?