# Control the colour of multiple drop shadow filter in svg

Tags: svg, vector, graphics, visualization

I am trying to apply multiple dropshadow effects - each with a different colour using SVG, I can position the elements perfectly but I cannot figure out how to colour them independently. The following gets me 90% there but both shadows are the same colour:

```
    <svg className={style.svg} viewBox={`0 0 150 150`}>
      <defs>
        <filter id="drop-shadow" x="-100%" y="-100%" width="300%" height="300%">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2" />

          <feColorMatrix
            in="offOut"
            type="matrix"
            values="0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 1 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"
          />
          <feOffset dx="-5" dy="5" result="offsetblur" />
          <feOffset dx="10" dy="-10" result="offsetblur2" in="blur" />
          <feComponentTransfer result="shadow1" in="offsetblur">
            <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.3" />
          </feComponentTransfer>
          <feComponentTransfer result="shadow2" in="offsetblur2">
            <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.3" />
          </feComponentTransfer>
          <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode in="shadow1" />
            <feMergeNode in="shadow2" />
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
          </feMerge>
        </filter>
      </defs>

      <circle
        stroke="#ff00ff"
        fill="#ff00ff"
        cx=75
        cy=75
        r=55
        strokeWidth=15
        filter="url(#drop-shadow)"
      />

    </svg>
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/c0un7z3r0/pen/KKzwQxN)

I copied this from one of the recommended answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756224/svg-multiple-effects-in-one-filter) on stack overflow but I cant tailor it for my specific purposes. How do I colour each shadow independently?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit more performant to use color matrix vs. component transfer if you can - browsers can do color matrix on the GPU. You can also get rid of a few steps and specify colors directly using the fifth column. SourceAlpha has color channels set to zero/black - so applying a multiplier them doesn't do anything.

```html
<svg className={style.svg} viewBox={`0 0 150 150`}>
      <defs>
        <filter id="drop-shadow" x="-100%" y="-100%" width="300%" height="300%">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2" />
            <feColorMatrix
              type="matrix"
              values="0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0.3 0"
            />
          <feOffset dx="-5" dy="5" result="shadow1" />
          <feOffset dx="10" dy="-10" result="offsetblur2" />
          <feColorMatrix type="matrix" result="shadow2"
              values="0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1 0"
            />            
          </feComponentTransfer>
          <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode in="shadow1" />
            <feMergeNode in="shadow2" />
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
          </feMerge>
        </filter>
      </defs>

      <circle
        stroke="#ff00ff"
        fill="#ff00ff"
        cx=75
        cy=75
        r=55
        strokeWidth=15
        filter="url(#drop-shadow)"
      />

    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the feFuncR/G/B tag to change the filter colour like so:

```
      <defs>
        <filter id="drop-shadow" x="-100%" y="-100%" width="300%" height="300%">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5" />
          <feOffset dx="-15" dy="15" result="offsetblur" />
          <feOffset dx="25" dy="-25" result="offsetblur2" in="blur" />
          <feComponentTransfer result="shadow1" in="offsetblur">
            <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.3" />
          </feComponentTransfer>
          <feComponentTransfer result="shadow2" in="offsetblur2">
            <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.2" />
            <feFuncR type="linear" slope="2.0" intercept="1" />
            <feFuncG type="linear" slope="2.0" intercept="1" />
            <feFuncB type="linear" slope="2.0" intercept="1" />
          </feComponentTransfer>
          <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode in="shadow1" />
            <feMergeNode in="shadow2" />
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
          </feMerge>
        </filter>
      </defs>
```

Posting the answer so that it might help others in the same position.